# Aligning PacBio HiFi reads to reference genome using pbmm2

Tags: sequence-alignment, reference-genome, pacbio, errors, bioconda

I am trying to align a yeast strain sequenced by PacBio HiFi reads to the reference genome S288C (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/data-hub/genome/GCF_000146045.2/) using pbmm2 but for some reason I am getting an error that I don't understand.

I first indexed the reference sequence with the following code:

```
pbmm2 index S288Cseq.fa S288Cindx.mmi
```

And then I attempted to align using this line of code:

```
pbmm2 align S288Cseq.mmi 088.fastq.gz mapped088.aligned.bam
```

But I keep getting this error:

`ERROR: unsupported extension on input file: S288Cindx.mmi`

I get that error no matter if I use the reference file in either mmi or the fasta format. Can someone please help and let me know what I'm doing wrong? (I downloaded the tool using bioconda: `conda install -c bioconda pbmm2` just in case that helps)

Comment: What happens if you try directly using the fasta in the alignment command? Indexing is optional.

Comment: Can you clarify what version of pbmm2 you are using? `pbmm2 --version` or something like that.

Comment: The same error comes up if I use the fasta file too. The version is: 

pbmm2 0.8.1 (commit cbf547249)

Comment: I used minimap2 in its place for now and it worked that way but I want to see if I can still use this tool

Comment: Looking more closely, the index filename changes ( `S288Cseq.mmi1 vs. S288Cindx.mmi`). Maybe this is just a typo but it's worth confirming that nothing else is weird.